# Python Appium "Swipe" action is not working with TouchAction

Tags: appium, appium-android, python-appium

I am working on automating an app where I need to swipe right 4 times to activate test mode. Since driver.swipe() was deprecated, I am unable to figure out what I am doing wrong while using the TouchAction class.

Code:

```
 actions = TouchAction(self.driver)
 actions.press(el=None, x=86, y=422).move_to(el=None, x=877, y=422).release().perform()
 actions.press(el=None, x=86, y=422).move_to(el=None, x=877, y=422).release().perform()
 actions.press(el=None, x=86, y=422).move_to(el=None, x=877, y=422).release().perform()
 actions.press(el=None, x=86, y=422).move_to(el=None, x=877, y=422).release().perform()
 actions.press(el=None, x=86, y=422).move_to(el=None, x=877, y=422).release().perform()
```

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, the swipe method was not working with the AVD Android emulator.

This code is correct, and ran when utilizing a different emulator (SauceLabs).

This code could have also been accomplished by using the ActionHelpers.swipe() method:
https://github.com/appium/pythonclient/blob/master/appium/webdriver/extensions/action_helpers.py#L130